# How check the c4v symmetry in a hamiltonian?without using geometry

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry

In the 2D square ssh model, how to check that the Hamiltonian does not change under c4v symmetry. Based on the square geometry of this model, it is possible to realize the existence of c4v symmetry, but I cannot get the Hamiltonian irreducibility.
For example, when I subjected the Hamiltonian to a 90-degree rotation, I did not reach the initial Hamiltonian.
The Hamiltonian of this model is located in the link below.
DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.075437

we choose the point group C4v with symmetry operations as follows:
arXiv
https://arxiv.org › quant-ph
[1308.6179] PT-symmetry broken by point-group ...

Also the transformation of hamiltonian with 90-degree rotation do as follows:
https://www.brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html

Comment: It would be better if you could reproduce the appropriate equations in your post.